# i cannot login to admin account username password everything correct but cannot login please help

Tags: login

I am Not log in to admin account

Username And Password is Correct but cannot log

**please help.**

Answer (score 0):

> **I have no idea what the problem might be, but you can still get access by creating another admin account:**

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="USERNAME_HERE" --admin-password="YOUR PASSWORD HERE" --admin-email="your-email-here@email.com" --admin-firstname="FIRST NAME HERE" --admin-lastname="LAST NAME HERE"
```

**After this you should use the new account to login and try to see what's wrong with your old account.**

Comment: how to get and how to reset ?

Comment: using this commad you can create a new admin account

Comment: and after login with new account you can set old account password

Comment: this command should be used in Magento developer portal right ?

Comment: we only have the admin access from the hosting company .

Comment: no using terminal , command

Comment: where and how? i have only access to admin but now i cannot .

Comment: to another way to create admin account you can create custom script and put in to magento root..

Answer (score 0):

If you using putty login to putty and direct to Magento directory path.
And then run below command.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="USERNAME_HERE" --admin-password="YOUR PASSWORD HERE" --admin-email="your-email-here@email.com" --admin-firstname="FIRST NAME HERE" --admin-lastname="LAST NAME HERE"
```

The above command will create new user.
After login to admin go to admin user and check what is the issue with old user which you were trying to login.

If you did not find anything in magento admin then login to Database check for admin_user table and check.